# how to convert date field from a excel sheet

Tags: php, laravel

**Note : I retrieved $dateString from my excel**

```
 $dateString = "29/07/2008 7:51:00 PM";
 $timestamp = date('Y-m-d h:i a', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $dateString)));
 echo  $timestamp;
```

> Output I get
>   **2029-07-08 12:00 am**

But I need output something like this. Please assist me

**2008-07-29 7:51:00**

Comment: your code is fine and its working perfectly on my local machine

Comment: But its not working in my localhost. I get Output like this 2029-07-08 12:00 am

Comment: https://3v4l.org/gIkVg

Comment: Please check your system date (year, month, date).

Comment: I retrieved my date field from my excel. I think its cause any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$date = "29/07/2008 7:51:00 PM";
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: @Siva Ganesh: Thanks for accepted my answer. Feel free to upvote this as answer if our solution addressed your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Use `H:i:s` instead `h:i a` .your code should be like this

```
 $dateString = "29/07/2008 7:51:00 PM";
 $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', 
   $dateString)));
 echo  $timestamp;
```

Comment: Let me check bro

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove 'a' to get rid of AM / PM

and you need an 'H' instead of 'h' to change 7:14 pm to 19:14

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $dateString)));
```

Comment: having a Capital H is what was missing, I have edited the same should work now. 'H' makes sure 7:14 PM translates to 19:14 . verified in http://phpfiddle.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use `g` for hour without leading zeros

```
$dateString = "29/07/2008 7:51:00 PM";
 $timestamp = date('Y-m-d g:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $dateString)));
 echo  $timestamp;
```

Comment: This code is works in my localhost, I get `2008-07-29 7:51:00` maybe you should explode the day, month, and year

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel you should try `Carbon`

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d h:i:s", $dateString);
$timestamp = $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

Or you should try this one also

```
list($day,$month,$year, $hour, $minute, $dayType) = preg_split('/[\/\s:]+/', $dateString); 
    echo $date = $year . '-' . $month. '-' .  $day . ' ' . ($dayType == "PM"?$hour+12: $hour) . ":" . $minute . ":00";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try IT.....

```
$dateString = "29/07/2008 7:51:00 PM";

$timestamp = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $dateString)));
echo  $timestamp;
```

> Output: 2008-07-29 07:51:00